# Why firstVisibleItem is -1 sometimes on onScroll of OnScrollListener in Android?

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

There is the `ListView` which has header view and registered `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` to load more items.

Added header view to ListView:

```
headerView = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
headerView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

Callback for OnScrollListener:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    ...
}
```

When checking parameters on `onScroll`, `firstVisibleItem` value is weird and is returned as **-1** suddenly after scrolling down little.

Logcat:

```
firstVisibleItem= 0 , visibleItemCount= 5 , totalItemCount= 22
firstVisibleItem= 0 , visibleItemCount= 5 , totalItemCount= 22
firstVisibleItem= 0 , visibleItemCount= 5 , totalItemCount= 22
firstVisibleItem= -1 , visibleItemCount= 6 , totalItemCount= 22
firstVisibleItem= -1 , visibleItemCount= 6 , totalItemCount= 22
```

is there anyone who knows the reason?

Comment: Where did you attach the ScrollListener?

Comment: @MuratK. after setting ListAdapter on `onActivityCreated`